# SpringBoot classpath maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've added this postgres dependency into my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm starting my service using `mvn spring-boot:run`. I'm getting this error message:

> Cannot load driver class: "org.postgresql.Driver"

I've took a look in generaed `jar` file into `BOOT-INF\lib\`

[image]

My `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true

  liquibase: 
    enabled: false

  profiles:
    active: 'local'
```

And my `application-local.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db"
spring.datasource.username: "username"
spring.datasource.password: "password"
spring.datasource.driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
```

Comment: delete the postgres jar file from local maven repo (.m2) & let maven download it again, this might be because of the jar file not downloaded properly.

Comment: You don't need to specify spring.datasource.driverClassName in application.properties. Remove it.